# Configure layer in MapServer 7.2 with 2 dimension (time and depth)

Tags: wms, vector, mapserver

I am trying to configure MapServer in order to serve a vector layer with 2 dimensions (time and depth) using a tileindex shapefile.

In the mapfile I define the main layer and the tileindex layer as below:

```
  # *********************************************************
  # MAIN LAYER
  # *********************************************************
  LAYER
    NAME "Currents-Vector"
    STATUS OFF
    CONNECTIONTYPE UVRASTER
    DEBUG 5

    METADATA
      "wms_name"    "Currents-Vector"
      "wms_title"   "Currents-Vector"
      
      "wms_enable_request"          "GetCapabilities GetMap GetLegendGraphic"
      "wms_server_version"          "1.3.0"
      "wms_feature_info_mime_type"  "text/html text/xml application/json"
      "gml_include_items"           "all"
      "wms_srs"                     "EPSG:3857"
      "wms_extent"                  "-180 -90 180 90"
      "ows_srs"                     "EPSG:3857"
      "ows_extent"                  "-180 -90 180 90"
      
      "wms_dimensionlist"           "time, depth"
      "wms_timeitem"                "time"
      "wms_timeextent"              "2021-12-27T00:00:00Z/2022-01-21T23:00:00Z/PT1H"
      "wms_timeformat"              "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ"

      "wms_depth_item"              "depth"
      "wms_depth_extent"            "0, 30, 130, 360, 1000"
      "wms_depth_units"             "meters"
      
    END # METADATA

    TILEINDEX "idx_07"
    TILEITEM "location"

    PROCESSING "BANDS=1,2"
    PROCESSING "UV_SPACING=28"
    PROCESSING "UV_SIZE_SCALE=100"

    PROJECTION
      "proj=latlong"
    END # PROJECTION
    
    
    TYPE POINT
    UNITS METERS
    CLASS
      STYLE
        ANGLE [uv_angle]
        COLOR 20 20 20
        GEOMTRANSFORM "end"
        MAXSIZE 30
        MINSIZE 15
        SIZE [uv_length]
        SYMBOL "vectorSymbol"
      END # STYLE
    END # CLASS
  END # LAYER
  
  # *********************************************************
  # TILEINDEX LAYER
  # *********************************************************    
  LAYER
    NAME "idx_07"
    DATA "index_07"      # -> path to shapefile used as tileindex 
    METADATA
      "wms_enable_request"  "*"
    END # METADATA
    
    STATUS OFF
    TILEITEM "location"
    TYPE TILEINDEX
    UNITS METERS
  END # LAYER
```

Each row in the Tileindex Shapfile table has 3 attributes, similar to the following:

```
LOCATION: NETCDF:"/test-app-v2/data/20211227_05_07_1000_h.nc":curr
TIME:     2021-12-27T05:00:00Z      
DEPTH:    1000
```

The GetCapabilities request to Mapserver returns a correct answer, showing the 2 dimensions (time and depth):

```
<Layer queryable="0" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
   <Name>Currents-Vector</Name>
   <Title>Currents-Vector</Title>
   <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
   <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
      <westBoundLongitude>-180</westBoundLongitude>
      <eastBoundLongitude>180</eastBoundLongitude>
      <southBoundLatitude>-90</southBoundLatitude>
      <northBoundLatitude>90</northBoundLatitude>
   </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
   <BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857" minx="-2.00375e+07" miny="-2.00375e+07" maxx="2.00375e+07" maxy="2.00375e+07" />
   <Dimension name="time" units="ISO8601" nearestValue="0">2021-12-27T00:00:00Z/2022-01-21T23:00:00Z/PT1H</Dimension>
   <Dimension name="depth" units="meters"  multipleValues="1"  nearestValue="0">0, 30, 130, 360, 1000</Dimension>
   <MetadataURL type="TC211">
      <Format>text/xml</Format>
      <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="https://test-app-v2/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=APP&amp;request=GetMetadata&amp;layer=Currents-Vector"/>
   </MetadataURL>
</Layer>
```

The problem is that a GetMap request like this:

```
https://test-app-v2/cgi-bin/mapserv?bbox=-626172.1357121639,4304933.433021129,-547900.6187481434,4383204.949985149&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=Currents-Vector&time=2022-01-19T10:00:00&dim_depth=360&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.3.0&width=256&height=256&map=/test-app-v2/APP.map&crs=EPSG%3A3857
```

causes an error in the log file:

```
msUVRASTERLayerInitItemInfo(): OGR error. Invalid Field name: depth
```

and no tiles is returned.

Comment: Could this be a CASE issue.  In the data is the depth data actually in field called DEPTH?

Comment: Hi @nmtoken, thanks for your comment. It is not a CASE issue, I tried both uppercase and lowercase.  About data, absolutely not, there is no "depth" field But According to my understanding the link should be in the **Tileindex shapefile** where each line looks like similar to this: (**LOCATION: NETCDF: "/test-app-v2/data/20211227_05_07_1000_h.nc":curr, TIME: 2021-12-27T05:00:00Z, DEPTH:1000**)
So, when I ask for data with the parameters (**time: 2021-12-27T05:00:00Z
depth: 1000**) Mapserver should understand that the data file is -> NETCDF: "/test-app-v2/data/20211227_05_07_1000_h.nc":curr

Comment: Similar issue ~ https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2014-June/076552.html ~ `msOGRLayerInitItemInfo(): OGR error. Invalid Field name: Time".`